# Using cases environment in optidef constraint causes error message

Tags: amsmath, optidef

I am trying to use the `optidef` package to typeset an optimization problem. I would like to use the `cases` environment in one of the constraints but LaTeX keeps complaining about an additional `}` that I cannot seem to find. This is a MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[short,nocomma]{optidef}

\begin{document}
\begin{mini!}
  % Variables
  {x,f}
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  % Objective function %
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  {%
    \sum_{\{i,j\} \in E} c_{\{i,j\}} x_{\{i,j\}}\label{prob:mst:obj}
  }
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  % Problem label and result %
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  {%
    \label{prob:mst}
  }{%
    % left empty on purpose
  }
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  % First constraint %
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \addConstraint{%
    % LHS
    \sum_{(i,j) \in \delta^+(i)} f_{(i,j)} - \sum_{(j,i) \in \delta^-(i)} f_{(j,i)}
  }{%
    % RHS
    =\,
    \begin{cases}
      \vert V \vert -1 & i=r\\
      -1               & i\neq r
    \end{cases}
    \label{prob:mst:cnstr2}
  }{%
    % Description or quantification
    \quad\forall i \in V
  }
\end{mini!}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This is a snippet taken from the `.log` file:

```
./mwe.tex:41: Argument of \reserved@a has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.41 \end{mini!}
                
I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.

Runaway argument?
{\def \@currenvir {cases}\edef \@currenvline {\on@line }\csuse {@begi\ETC.
./mwe.tex:41: Paragraph ended before \reserved@a was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.41 \end{mini!}
                
I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.

./mwe.tex:41: Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.41 \end{mini!}
                
I've put in what seems to be necessary to fix
the current column of the current alignment.
Try to go on, since this might almost work.

./mwe.tex:41: Extra }, or forgotten $.
<template> }
            $}\ifmeasuring@ \savefieldlength@ \fi \set@field \hfil \endtempl...
l.41 \end{mini!}
                
I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.

./mwe.tex:41: Argument of \reserved@a has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.41 \end{mini!}
                
I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.

Runaway argument?
{\def \@currenvir {cases}\edef \@currenvline {\on@line }\csuse {@begi\ETC.
./mwe.tex:41: Paragraph ended before \reserved@a was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.41 \end{mini!}
                
I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.

./mwe.tex:41: Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.41 \end{mini!}
                
I've put in what seems to be necessary to fix
the current column of the current alignment.
Try to go on, since this might almost work.

./mwe.tex:41: Extra }, or forgotten $.
<template> }
            $}\ifmeasuring@ \savefieldlength@ \fi \set@field \hfil \endtempl...
l.41 \end{mini!}
                
I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.
```

As you can see above, the generated PDF looks fine (so why complain then?) but I still wanted to know if others have had the same issue and whether it is safe to ignore the error message for now.

Comment: I get the errors only if I run TeX Live 2016. Isn't it time to upgrade?

Comment: @egreg To be fair, I get the error also with TeXLive2017 `;-)` Sadly upgrading is not always an option.

Comment: @campa Not with `optidef 2017/11/29 - version=2.6` which I have on my TeX Live 2017 distribution. In my TL 2016, the version of `optidef` is 2.3

Comment: @egreg Oh, I see, I've got `2017/05/24 - version=2.4`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can only reproduce the issue by running TeX Live 2016 (that in its final state has `optidef` version 2.3).

With TL 2017 and `optidef` version 2.6 the issue doesn't appear, nor with later versions.

If you cannot upgrade your TeX system from TL 2016 (or 2017) to the current release, there is a workaround: wrap the `cases` environment in `\unexpanded`.

```
\unexpanded{\begin{cases}...\end{cases}}
```

Comment: Thank you! I asked my system admin for an upgrade (problem solved), so I didn't get to try out the workaround you suggested. I'll keep the `\unexpanded` trick in memory, though - it may come in handy in the future.